# WSO2 ESB and IS Integration: handler tag is missing when we open the api source

Tags: wso2, handler, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have created a API with name plantsapi and here is my api definition

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="plantsapi" context="/plantsapi">
<resource methods="POST DELETE PUT GET">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Message Flow" value="Plant Search API API - IN"></property>
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD IS###########" expression="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD"></property>
        <property name="ip address" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"></property>
        <property name="In Time : " expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"></property>
     </log>
     <property name="TIME_IN" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"></property>
     <property name="xacml_use_rest" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
     <property name="xacml_resource_prefix" value="/SearchService/api/plants" scope="axis2"></property>
     <property name="xacml_resource_prefix_only" value="true" scope="axis2"></property>
     <entitlementService remoteServiceUrl="https://172.20.13.153:9443/services" remoteServiceUserName="admin" remoteServicePassword="enc:kuv2MubUUveMyv6GeHrXr9il59ajJIqUI4eoYHcgGKf/BBFOWn96NTjJQI+wYbWjKW6r79S7L7ZzgYeWx7DlGbff5X3pBN2Gh9yV0BHP1E93QtFqR7uTWi141Tr7V7ZwScwNqJbiNoV+vyLbsqKJE7T3nP8Ih9Y6omygbcLcHzg=" callbackClass="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.callback.UTEntitlementCallbackHandler" client="basicAuth">
        <onReject>
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="Message Flow" value="REJECTED@"></property>
           </log>
           <property name="HTTP_SC" value="401" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
           <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <oatherizationresponse xmlns="">Not Authorized </oatherizationresponse>
              </format>
              <args></args>
           </payloadFactory>
           <respond></respond>
        </onReject>
        <onAccept>
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="Message Flow" value="ACCEPTED@"></property>
           </log>
           <send>
              <endpoint>
                 <address uri="http://172.20.13.153:8080/plant-service/api/"></address>
              </endpoint>
           </send>
           <property name="TIME_OUT" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"></property>
           <script language="js">var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_IN");var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_OUT");var timeTaken = time2 - time1;mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeTaken);</script>
           <log level="custom">
              <property name="Time Duration in ms:" expression="get-property('RESPONSE_TIME') "></property>
           </log>
        </onAccept>
        <obligations></obligations>
        <advice></advice>
     </entitlementService>
  </inSequence>
</resource>
<handlers>
     <handler class="org.wso2.handler.SimpleOauthHandlerNew">
  </handler>
</handlers>
</api>
```

Whenever I open the source view of the above API the handler tag is missing. and always getting 202 response. I am using wso2 ESB 4.8.1

Could you please advice me where is the mistake and how to sort out.

Regards,
Geetha

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug[1]. It will be fixed in ESB 4.9.0 (will be released soon). So don't update the API source view. If you update, you will loose the handlers.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3395

Answer (score 0):

And the solution is to use [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/). WSO2 does not recommend using the UI to do development, it is mainly used to monitor and view the instance.